# How to map JSON Link to Object

Tags: java, jackson, jersey, jax-rs

I have this JSON media data:

```
"links": [
{
  "type": "string",
  "title": "string",
  "rel": "string",
  "uri": "string",
  "rels": [
    "string"
  ],
  "uriBuilder": {},
  "params": {}
}]
```

I would like to map it to this response object:

```
@ApiModel(value = "Example")
@JsonPropertyOrder({ "links"})
public class ExampleResponse {

    @ApiModelProperty
    private List<Link> links = new ArrayList<Link>();

    public List<Link> getLinks() {
        return links;
    }

    public void setLinks(ArrayList<Link> links) {
        this.links = links;
    }
```

However I keep getting this exception

```
Cannot construct instance of `javax.ws.rs.core.Link` (although at least one Creator exists): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator) at [Source: (org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$UnCloseableInputStream); line: 13, column: 7] (through reference chain: ex.src.ExampleResponse["links"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])
```

Is it even possible to do?

Comment: You should make you own (de)serializer for the links.

Comment: Why does the JSON media data contain both `rel` and `rels`? Why does it contain `uriBuilder`? Why does it contain `params`, which contains the other values again? As Paul said, you need to provide a custom (de)serializer, or you need to use a different `Link` implementation that only contain the real fields to use. That implementation can use `javax.ws.rs.core.Link` internally, if needed.

Comment: @PaulSamsotha  Probably a stupid question, but how do I make a deserialiser for the links?

Comment: Google "custom Jackson serializer/deserializer". Thes use a ContextResolver to configure the ObjectMapper. You can google that too.

Comment: Did you figure it out? Post it as an answer if you did. Note, you will need to register the ContextResolver both on the server side _and_ the client side (if you are using the Jersey client to call the endpoint).